# Problem Accessing Specific Site More Than Once/Few Times - Strange Internet Connection

Tags: internet-connection, cookies, 3g

I recently upgraded to 3G wireless data connection. The problem with my internet connection is after visiting a given website few times, the server stops responding. I later open that website in incognito mode on chrome or private browsing mode on Firefox and that works fine. Even if I just clear the browser cookies/cache the website starts responding. And even if restart the browser web sites start responding properly. It happens with me with almost all the website atleast once which I visit regularly.

Due to some reason I have changed the operating system from fedora to debian but even after that the issue persists.

I am technically clueless why this is happening. Anyone can help?

Update:

traceroute and ping for the site which I cannot access on the browser

```
idlecool@spark:~$ traceroute mail.google.com
traceroute to mail.google.com (74.125.73.17), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  netgear (192.168.1.1)  0.606 ms  1.110 ms  1.401 ms
 2  tiger (10.0.0.1)  4.112 ms  4.193 ms  4.294 ms
 3  218.248.84.7 (218.248.84.7)  130.586 ms  129.469 ms  147.456 ms
 4  10.42.43.105 (10.42.43.105)  127.779 ms  128.688 ms  137.209 ms
 5  10.42.43.76 (10.42.43.76)  134.357 ms  156.716 ms  157.190 ms
 6  172.24.12.10 (172.24.12.10)  176.668 ms  177.197 ms  177.940 ms
 7  218.248.255.82 (218.248.255.82)  295.852 ms  293.605 ms  293.848 ms
 8  * 59.163.206.189.static.chennai.vsnl.net.in (59.163.206.189)  349.098 ms  348.861 ms
 9  121.240.1.46 (121.240.1.46)  317.653 ms  306.365 ms  305.397 ms
10  72.14.232.110 (72.14.232.110)  305.849 ms  325.741 ms 72.14.233.204 (72.14.233.204)  325.221 ms
11  66.249.94.74 (66.249.94.74)  326.381 ms  344.757 ms  345.468 ms
12  66.249.94.92 (66.249.94.92)  375.065 ms  375.701 ms  376.339 ms
13  66.249.94.121 (66.249.94.121)  405.225 ms  406.024 ms  406.557 ms
14  64.233.174.176 (64.233.174.176)  407.447 ms  409.364 ms *
15  64.233.174.141 (64.233.174.141)  379.769 ms  378.182 ms  377.690 ms
16  209.85.243.178 (209.85.243.178)  377.155 ms  386.813 ms 216.239.47.121 (216.239.47.121)  406.729 ms
17  216.239.46.59 (216.239.46.59)  387.357 ms 216.239.46.39 (216.239.46.39)  427.037 ms 216.239.46.59 (216.239.46.59)  427.533 ms
18  72.14.232.45 (72.14.232.45)  446.892 ms 72.14.232.49 (72.14.232.49)  436.153 ms 72.14.232.53 (72.14.232.53)  446.071 ms
19  tul01m01-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.73.17)  467.652 ms  466.840 ms  466.040 ms
idlecool@spark:~$ ping mail.google.com
PING googlemail.l.google.com (74.125.73.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.73.17): icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=359 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.73.17): icmp_req=2 ttl=48 time=358 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.73.17): icmp_req=3 ttl=48 time=358 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.73.17): icmp_req=4 ttl=48 time=379 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.73.17): icmp_req=5 ttl=48 time=358 ms
^C
--- googlemail.l.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 358.835/363.014/379.189/8.123 ms
idlecool@spark:~$
```

traceroute and ping for the site which i can access

```
idlecool@spark:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (74.125.73.99), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  netgear (192.168.1.1)  0.550 ms  1.179 ms  1.454 ms
 2  tiger (10.0.0.1)  5.435 ms  5.544 ms  5.659 ms
 3  218.248.84.7 (218.248.84.7)  139.269 ms  138.341 ms  157.971 ms
 4  10.42.43.109 (10.42.43.109)  117.950 ms  118.783 ms  140.884 ms
 5  10.42.43.76 (10.42.43.76)  139.570 ms  158.586 ms  159.176 ms
 6  172.24.12.10 (172.24.12.10)  177.578 ms  178.156 ms  178.215 ms
 7  218.248.255.82 (218.248.255.82)  306.581 ms  303.297 ms  303.884 ms
 8  59.163.206.161.static.chennai.vsnl.net.in (59.163.206.161)  462.076 ms  350.492 ms  369.016 ms
 9  121.240.1.46 (121.240.1.46)  309.589 ms  305.946 ms  298.600 ms
10  72.14.233.204 (72.14.233.204)  298.970 ms 72.14.232.110 (72.14.232.110)  318.869 ms 72.14.233.204 (72.14.233.204)  318.128 ms
11  66.249.94.72 (66.249.94.72)  319.465 ms 66.249.94.74 (66.249.94.74)  498.938 ms  499.394 ms
12  66.249.94.104 (66.249.94.104)  500.080 ms 66.249.94.92 (66.249.94.92)  507.943 ms  505.290 ms
13  66.249.94.121 (66.249.94.121)  501.409 ms 66.249.94.106 (66.249.94.106)  508.727 ms 66.249.94.121 (66.249.94.121)  501.013 ms
14  64.233.174.176 (64.233.174.176)  503.096 ms 64.233.174.178 (64.233.174.178)  502.746 ms *
15  64.233.174.143 (64.233.174.143)  379.890 ms  697.027 ms 64.233.174.141 (64.233.174.141)  397.791 ms
16  209.85.243.178 (209.85.243.178)  377.886 ms  407.891 ms 216.239.47.121 (216.239.47.121)  409.336 ms
17  216.239.46.61 (216.239.46.61)  408.650 ms 216.239.46.39 (216.239.46.39)  417.142 ms  427.110 ms
18  72.14.232.49 (72.14.232.49)  437.781 ms 72.14.232.45 (72.14.232.45)  437.141 ms 72.14.232.49 (72.14.232.49)  438.289 ms
19  tul01m01-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.73.99)  477.105 ms  477.623 ms  478.203 ms
idlecool@spark:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.73.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.73.99): icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=369 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.73.99): icmp_req=2 ttl=48 time=368 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.73.99): icmp_req=3 ttl=48 time=369 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.73.99): icmp_req=4 ttl=48 time=369 ms
64 bytes from tul01m01-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.73.99): icmp_req=5 ttl=48 time=368 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 368.877/369.108/369.437/0.229 ms
idlecool@spark:~$
```

Comment: Some standard network tests: What happens when you `traceroute` to the server? `ping`? Are you encrypting your connection? What kind of websites are you going to?

Comment: @digitxp: updated my question

Comment: To eliminate the possibility of DNS issues, could you check on Windows, if you have a copy installed? (For some reason Windows's DNS always worked better for me.)

Comment: I use Google Open DNS. and in case DNS would be the issue, I never would be able to ping the servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symptoms sound like a caching issue. Are you using a card or are you tethering wirelessly to your cell phone? Either your provider's caching server isn't doing a very good job, or some other device in your LAN -- a modem, router, or firewall -- is having problems. (Do you have any such devices? If so, remove them and see if the issue disappears. Also try connecting to another network to see if the issues persist; if they do, the problem is local to your machine and not related to your connection.)

If you're certain the issue is specific to your provider, though, and you have no other devices in your network, call tech support and tell them you're having issues with their cache servers; they'll probably have a solution for you.